# Receiving Messages From Websocket Scala

Tags: javascript, scala, websocket

I'm trying to configure a WebSocket in Scala. I have a function that broadcasts a bunch of JSON to a WebSocket. It works when I configure it through http://www.websocket.org/echo.html (inputting my own ws://localhost:9000/web-socket), but I need it to display the information on a new webpage.

To that effect I made a new webpage called client which is defined in my controllers as

```
def client = Action {
   val data = new RedshiftData() // get the data
   Ok(views.html.client(data))
}
```

In my views I have client.scala.html defined as (adapted from websockets.org)

```
@import datadump.RedshiftData
@(data: RedshiftData)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>
        var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9000/web-socket";

        var ws = new WebSocket(wsUri);
        @data.pushToWebSocket

        ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
            var msg = JSON.parse(evt.data);
            console.log(msg);
        };

  </script>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

But, it never receives my message that I'm sending. How do I get it to listen to the message that I send out in the controller?